# Как собрать библиотеку из исходников под x32 разрядную систему?

Tags: c++, linux, curl, библиотеки

Написал небольшую программу. Теперь необходимо портировать её для запуска на 32-разрядной системе. Для работы была использована библиотека cURL, которую я собрал из исходников. Как я понимаю, теперь мне нужно пересобрать ей с указанием требуемой системы (видимо, при вызове `./configure` нужно указать какой-то параметр). Не могли бы вы подсказать, что именно мне нужно выполнить, для сборки библиотеки?
P.S. программа будет запускаться на процессоре armhf, если это важно.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду `libcurl` (https://curl.haxx.se/)? Обычно во всех дистрибутивах это достигается либо через механизм multilib, либо путём пересборки (для таких, как Gentoo, Buildroot, Yocto и т.п.). Скорее всего вас интересует второй случай, и скорее всего кросс-компиляция. Используйте дистрибутивы в исходниках, там всё это задаётся через общий конфигурационный файл.

Comment: А вообще, вопрос написан в стиле "у меня подземный стук", а именно много воды и мало конкретики.

Comment: armhf - это не просто "32-разрядная система", это ещё и "не-x86 система". Т.е. Ваша утилита должна быть скомпилирована под ARM, и для этого надо иметь подходящий компилятор и все необходимые библиотеки. Для начала можно погуглить "cross compiler".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> нужно пересобрать её с указанием требуемой системы (видимо, при вызове
>   ./configure нужно указать какой-то параметр)

Если это "нормальный" скрипт *configure*, то у него должен быть параметр --target=<целевая платформа> 
Под словом "платформа" понимается триада, разделённая знаками "-", которая кодирует архитектуру железа, целевую ос и вариант API этой ос.

Например: *arm-linux-gnueabihf*

Запустите *./configure --help* что бы узнать, как получить полный список поддерживаемых целей.

Но, даже если Ваш конфигуратор поддерживает необходимую Вам цель, дале не факт, что в системе установлены соответствующие кросс-утилиты.

Comment: Ага. Как я понял, мне нужно вызвать ./configure с тремя параметрами --target=<целевая платформа>,--host=<платформа, где я буду запускать программу>,--build=<платформа, где я буду собирать программу>.
Правда не совсем понятно, чем host отличается от target.
В итоге, вызывал `./configure --target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu`
Ну и по факту, даже установка компилятора `arm-linux-gnueabihf`(gcc и g++ -multilib почему-то были удалены в процессе его установки) мне ничем не помогла: не смог пока нормально настроить набор в Qt.

Comment: **Правда не совсем понятно, чем host отличается от target**  - host - там, где выполняется скрипт *configure*, build - там, где будет работать make по сгенерированному Makefile, target - там, где будет выполняться собранная программа. Для 99%  случаев host == build и определяется по умолчанию. Эти параметры лучше вообще не задавать.

Comment: **установка компилятора arm-linux-gnueabihf** - Здесь всё достаточно запутано. Устанавливайте только то, про что *configure* Вам скажет, что нет такого. В папке */usr* появится подкаталог вида arm-linux-gnueabihf. А в нём будут программы кросс-компилляторов. Проверьте, что они будут доступны через переменную PATH.